# select.one is not giving desired output in bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the following place "England, Swiss and India" from the below table.

[image]
I am using bs4 for that.

and here is what i am using

```
country=soup.select_one("span.table1.table__2--style1.table__3").
```

As a result, "country" get printed

How can i print the actual country instead i.e. Spain?

Also, when i try to get the languages, it gives me "Country" again

```
lang=soup.select_one("span.table1.table__2--style1.table__3").get_text()
    print(lang)
```

Result of lang is "Country" again

Can someone guide where am i wrong?

Comment: Can you share URL? That way we can see whole structure of the HTML document. `select_one()` selects only one element - if you call it with the same parameters, it will select the same element.